# Auto indent and pretty code by notepadqq

Tags: 14.04, text-editor, notepadqq

Before, in Windows, I used `notepad++` and it has an option `TextFX->Edit->Reindent C++ code` for reformatting code. Now I use `Ubuntu 14.0.4` so I use `notepadqq` as alternative for `notepad++`. How I can achieve a similar result in `notepadqq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepadqq doesn't have a auto-formatting code feature like the one in Notepad++. I recommend using SublimeText instead as an alternative. You can download it from their website https://www.sublimetext.com/3

There are plugins for autoformatting. One such plugin is [SublimeAStyleFormatter](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter). Install the plugin (Here is a [guide how to do that](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)). Once installed, you can autoformat C/C++ code by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> key combo.

Answer (score 0):

From top menu : Language -> C++ (or whatever language you like).

You can also change indentation width from Settings -> Preferences -> Languages.

Edit : It doesn't have auto indentation though.